# Int variable reinitialize in Content Script (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a global variable in my content script

```
var myint = 1;
var clicker;
```

Then I start the timer when the page is loaded (and store the timer id in `var clicker`)

```
window.onload = function () {
var elm = document.getElementById("my-container");
if (elm != undefined && elm != null) {
    localStorage['launched'] = "yes";        
} else {        
    clicker = setInterval(click, 30 * 1000);
}
}
```

This function will be called every 30 seconds (according to `setInterval`)

```
function click() {
//since myint is initialized with 1, this if should return true just once
if (myint > 0) {
    myint = myint - 1; //myint becomes 0 so if should fail from now on...
    clearInterval(clicker);
    document.getElementById('elementID').click();    
    alert("clicking now");        
}    
}
```

The problem is, when a link is clicked, it raises the windows.onload event again and therfore assigning the `clicker` variable a new timer id of setInterval.

However since `myint` is a global variable that I set to 0 inside my if, then the if should never return true and therefore I get to click only once (even though the timer will keep firing).

When I was debugging this I found out that everytime the `window.onload` is called, the `myint` immediately resets itself to 1 again.

How can I get `myint` to preserve its last state which is `0`??

EDIT #1

Here is my manifest.json

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "META Upgrader",
"version": "1.0.0",
"content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
}],
"permissions": [
"background", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "tabs", "<all_urls>"
],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["jsui.js"]
}
```

Comment: I think your content script has all_frames:true so it runs in all frames of the page which is what you observed as multiple onload.

Comment: @wOxxOm I edited the question and added my manifest.json, there is no `all_frames` should I add it as false? I was thinking this was because content script runs in the context of the page, so each time the page loads it starts with fresh variables...not sure though